# Strategy to find screen coordinates that span the entire canvas

Tags: qt, math, coordinate-transformation

I am writing an app to display bike rack stations in a city. I am pulling the coordinates from a json file and trying to convert the latitude/longitudes into screen coordinates.

The framework I am using (Qt) calculates y from top to bottom and x from left to right, so obviously I wrote conversion functions for this. The conversion functions look like this:

```
/* 
The minLatitude has already been calculated to be
the latitude of the southernmost rack

*/
qreal BikeRackSystem::getY(qreal latitude)
{
  qreal diffY = latitude - minLatitude;
  return height - (diffY*height);
}

/* 
The minLatitude has already been calculated to be
the latitude of the southernmost rack

*/
qreal BikeRackSystem::getX(qreal longitude)
{
  qreal diffX = longitude - minLongitude;
  return width * diffX;
}
```

However I end up with this kind of image

[image]

This is close, but not *quite* what I was looking for. How can I change my conversion functions to give me screen coordinates that span the whole screen?

Edit: If it is at all interesting...I am using [QGraphicsEllipseItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsellipseitem.html) subclasses to draw the racks on a [QGraphicsScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that my conversion function wasn't properly set up. I found the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295202/528617)

The crucial part mentioned in the answer was:

```
        x - min                                  max - min
f(x) = ---------   ===>   f(min) = 0;  f(max) =  --------- = 1
       max - min                                 max - min
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set the scene geometry to the view geometry. For example, you can overwrite the resize event of your QGraphicsView:

```
void MyQgraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    /* always resize the scene accordingly */
    if (scene())
        scene()->setSceneRect(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), event->size()));

    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

Then you can use the width and height of the scene for setting up your internal coordinate system. This is an example of a widget that would always auto-zoom the contents.

Often you don't want this (e.g. the user should be able to zoom and pan the map with the mouse). Then you should determine a good initial configuration of the `QGraphicsView`.
For this you can either use the `setSceneRect()` or the `setTransform()` method on the graphicsview. The latter is more powerful (e.g. it enables rotation), while the former is easier to use. In this case, you would set a generic scene size of your liking (e.g. 1-by-1) to ease the handling of internal coordinates. You might even use the latitudes and longitudes as x, y values and then let the transformation matrix handle it.

Comment: I don't think that's the real problem here. The real problem is that my conversion function isn't spreading the values out from 0 -> width

Comment: Good answer though, but I found a better solution (see below)