# how to calculate slider value from negative to positive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

i have a curve slider that takes in value from the height of the frame which value from -100 to 300 which i need to calculate it to equal the value of 0 to 10.

how can i calculate the negative value as what i had gotten was negative value?

my math is bad :(

```
     -(NSUInteger)calculatePoints:(float)pointY
{
    NSLog(@"maxOffsetValue %f minOffsetValue %fand pointY %f",maxOffsetValue,minOffsetValue, pointY);

    float value =  maxOffsetValue + minOffsetValue;
    NSLog(@"value %f",value);
    float normalValue = (pointY * 1.5) / value ;
    NSLog(@"normalValue %f",normalValue);

    return normalValue;
}
//set value from point
-(void) setValueFromPoint:(CGPoint) point
{
    [animationTimer invalidate]; 

    NSInteger value = [self calculatePoints:point.y];
    value = ((value / self.frame.size.height) * self.max);

    NSLog(@"raw value %d",value);
    value < 0 ? value = 0 : value;
    value > self.max ? value = self.max : value;
    self->_value = value;
    NSLog(@"Value %d",value);
}
```

Comment: Is it what you want `((point.y-(-100))/400) * 10` ?

Comment: @KudoCC awesome thanks it works!!
if u post it as an answer, i will accept it!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a short answer.

`((point.y-(-100))/400) * 10`

Comment: maybe you should enhance your short answer with some explanations

Comment: @user503413 It's hard to explain a math problem to me. I don't think it is a complicated formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your value scaled between `0` and `10` by using

```
(x + 100) / 40
```

where `x` is the value between `-100` and `300`.

---

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value)**