# Using scatter for two different data set doesn't work

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I want to show two different data in the same figure and I want to show densities of each data with colors. I used below code:

```
scatter(xm,ym,[],c/(max(c)),'filled','d')
hold on
scatter(x,y, [], dens,'filled','d')
```

but it only shows data (x,y) colored and data xm and ym are all red. When I use scatter(xm,ym,[],c/(max(c)),'filled','d') without using scatter(x,y, [], dens,'filled','d'), it shows xm and ym data colored.But when I use both scatters with a hold on between them, the error I mentioned occurs. How can I solve the problem? could anyone help?

Comment: This is a scaling problem, the 2 data sets are probably at different scales causing the second to seem constant. What do you want your output to look like exactly?

Comment: Yes, they have different scales. I want the first data (which have been used in the first scatter) to be shown as a background field which it's color in each position shows the amount of it in that position(for example if a region is red, it means that c is high in that region), and also I want the second data to be shown with different colours in position related to them. Is it clear now? @StackPlayer

Answer (score 0):

One clean option is to use 2 subplots, but it will not give you neatly the overlap you are looking for.

Another trick is to scale the background data values to 0-1, and the second data values to 1-2. And then plot them the way you are doing it. (this will distinguish the colors, and will keep them readable since the ranges are both of size 1).

Comment: How can I do these parts: to scale the background data values to 0-1, and the second data values to 1-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value

Comment: I used dens = (dens/max(dens));
    hold on
 sa=c./max(c)+1;
   scatter(xm,ym, [], sa ,'filled','d')
    scatter(x,y, [], dens,'filled','d') but the problem don't solve

Comment: I didn't understand the link