# Rescaling a set of numbers to a new scale

Tags: math

I am trying to rescale a set of numbers to a new scale with some specific requirements.

Imagine I have a set of numbers between 1-100

I want to be able to scale this set of numbers to a new scale between 80 - 120 where 80 is the min of the original set, 120 is the max of the original set and 100 is the mean.

To use a small example:

For the set [43,26,56,21,25,94]

On the new scale 21 would map to 80, 94 would map to 120, and 44.2 would map to 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale down a range of numbers with a known min and max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value)

Comment: What language are you doing it in, and what have you tried? Are you restricted to integers, or would you want floating point calculations?

Answer (score 3):

The map `f` that scales a range `[a b]` to `[c d]` is `f(x) = (x-a)*(d-c)/(b-a) + c`

However, I don't think it is possible to ensure a linear  `f` also maps the mean of arbitrary values in a set contained in the range `[a b]` to a specified value in the range `[c d]` (including the average of c and d).

For that, you will have to either scale `[a mean]` to `[c (c+d)/2)]` and `[mean b]` to `[(c+d)/2 d]` separately, or use some other non-linear mapping.