# How to get the output between 100 to 150?

Tags: java, android, logic

- I am trying to design a circle of textview whose height and width will be dynamic and should be between 100 to 150 dp.
- Now the dynamic values can be of any range but I want it between 100 to 150.
  for example if I get the dynamic value as 1000 or may be 3000.... I should be able to convert into numbers between 100 to 150.
- I am looking for the logic where I input a dynamic value(any range)... I get a integer between 100 to 150.

Comment: can it be random number between 100-150?

Comment: possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value

Comment: simplest way will be `number%50+100`

Comment: according to what logic should the input be "converted"?

Comment: Any random value between 100 - 150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a random value between 100 and 150

```
int low = 100;
int high = 150;
Random random = new Random();
int randomValue = random.nextInt(high - low + 1) + low;
```

If you need a random value between 100 and 150 based on a given dynamic value.

```
int dynamicValue = 1000; // or 3000 or any value
int low = 100;
int high = 150;
int randomValue = (dynamicValue % (high - low + 1)) + low;
```