# My linear map function is not giving right answers

Tags: c#, dictionary, math, mapping

This formula kinda don't work

I tried to use this formula but it looks like it won't give me right answers, I hope that I can use all values for a linear mapping I hope you guys can help me :) if I need to rewrite this post I would not mind

> All of the input is: map(200,1, value,0,1);
>   It never gives between 0 1.
>   Thank you again, guys, here is code

```
function map(max_value, first_bottom, first_top, second_top, second_bottom){
    y=(max_value - first_bottom) / (first_top - first_bottom) * 
    (second_top - second_bottom) + second_bottom;
}
```

Comment: why it has C# tag? this is not C# code ...

Comment: This looks to be JavaScript code, and the formula you're using isn't correct. Also, this has several answers already. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value) is the highest rated I could find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scale down a range of numbers with a known min and max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value)

Comment: @Selvin I test code on JS so it is kinda faster but implementing in c# sorry hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several great answers for this on the web ([here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value) and [there Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range) are two examples in SE networks alone).

However, it looks as though you've written the formula incorrectly. Below is a correct implementation broken down to better visualize the math that is happening.

```
function linearMap(currentValue, currentMin, currentMax, newMin, newMax) {
    var newSize = newMax - newMin;
    var oldSize = currentMax - currentMin;
    var oldScale = currentValue - currentMin;
    return (newSize * oldScale / oldSize) + newMin;
}
```

Feel free to give this a try over on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvp94gt1/) or [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u052pS). I've also included it in a snippet below in case either of those links die out.

```js
function linearMap(currentValue, currentMin, currentMax, newMin, newMax) {
    var newSize = newMax - newMin;
    var oldSize = currentMax - currentMin;
    var oldScale = currentValue - currentMin;
    return (newSize * oldScale / oldSize) + newMin;
}
var val = 8.3;
var oldMin = 0;
var oldMax = 10;
var newMin = 0;
var newMax = 1;
var result = linearMap(val, oldMin, oldMax, newMin, newMax).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("result").innerText = 'Mapping a value of ' + val +                           ' in an existing range of ' + oldMin +
                                              ' - ' + oldMax +
                                              ' to a new range of ' + newMin +
                                              ' - ' + newMax +
                                              ' yields a result of ' + result;
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fc0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #fc0, #ff0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #fc0, #ff0);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```