# How do I convert a point in a range to a different range?

Tags: c#, math

I would like to convert a "point" in a certain range to a point in a different range.

- `Range #1` consists of values between 0 and 1.
- `Range #2` consists of values between -1 and 1.

Now when I wanted to convert the point 0 of `range #1` to a point in `range #2`, I'd know that it would be -1 in `range #2`.

Now when I have the point 0.5 in `range #1`, what would be the formula to convert it a point in `range #2`?

I need this to recalculate a point on the screen for a game engine called Unity. It works with C#.

Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to do is known as scaling. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you want to calculate it manually... Lets say you have a value X in range from A to B and you want to get a value in a range from C to D.
This should do it:

1. Get initial range length:

   var length = B - A;
2. Calculate how far from the start the point X is located:

   var fromAtoX= X - A;
3. Get the position of X in percent:

   var fromAtoXinPercent = length / fromAtoX;
4. Get length of a new range:

   var newLength = D - C;
5. Calculate length from the start to the new point:

   var fromCtoX = newLength * fromAtoXinPercent;
6. Add it to the starting point and find new position:

   var newX = C + fromCtoX;

I hope it works.