# How to create a list of numbers that go up and down in Python?

Tags: python, list

I need to create a list in Python from a minimum and a maximum value. Half of the list needs to go up, and the other half needs to go down. Here's what I'm doing for now:

```
    random_data = np.random.uniform(min_value, max_value, 6))
    up_data = np.sort(random_data)
    down_data = -np.sort(-random_data)
    df = np.concatenate((up_data, down_data))
```

1. I create a list of 6 random numbers between a minimum and a maximum.
2. I sort them from down to up in a list.
3. I sort them from up to down in another list.
4. I put the two lists together.

It's working, but I don't like how it looks. I'm sure there must be a better way to do this but I just can't find anything. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it might be better suited for codereview.

Comment: @baduker Thank you I'll post it there!

Comment: @baduker, I have come to believe that over at codereview too this will be closed in a heartbeat.

Comment: @anurag Because it's good enough to stay like that or because I'm dumb and the question is stupid?

Comment: @SimonF.-Smith, what I meant was we can solve it here itself! Besides, a great author once said, "there are no dumb questions"

Comment: @anurag Haha alright!

Comment: generate values for `sin()` between `0 and pi`. Scale them up. That should do. Sin is monotonically increasing between `0 and pi/2` and decreasing between `pi/2 and pi`.

Comment: In case anybody is curious as to who said that, [here you go](https://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/12/how_to_build_a_.html) - Kathy Sierra, author of "Head First Java"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it intentional that both sides have the same numbers ?  If not, you should generate random numbers for the full size and concatenate ascending and descending sorts of half the values on each side:

```
import numpy as np
min_value = 75
max_value = 100
size      = 12

random_data = np.random.uniform(min_value, max_value, size)
left_side   = np.sort(random_data[::2])
right_side  = np.sort(random_data[1::2])[::-1]
df          = np.concatenate((left_side,right_side))
```

output:

```
print(df)
[84.35962408 84.86455724 84.86643652 85.95444697 86.97411648 95.55028286
 97.6394171  94.16644573 94.05654689 92.12869314 88.52363283 80.19109841]
```

You could also do it "in-place" directly in the resulting array:

```
df = np.random.uniform(min_value, max_value, size)
df[:size//2].sort()
df[size//2:][::-1].sort()
```

In normal Python (i.e. not using the numpy module), you can take a similar approach:

```
import random
values = [random.randrange(min_value,max_value) for _ in range(size)]
values[:size//2] = sorted(values[:size//2])
values[size//2:] = sorted(values[size//2:],reverse=True)

print(values)
# [78, 79, 80, 80, 87, 93, 98, 92, 90, 86, 85, 81]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's way better like this and you are right, I didn't want the same numbers on both side so that's a very good example you gave to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need this, but, here is the idea I suggested in comments:

```py
import math
import random

size = 20
dec = 3

mx = 113
mn = 67

domain = sorted([random.uniform(0, math.pi) for _ in range(size)])
use_this = [round(fctr * math.sin(x), dec) for x in domain]

mx_l = max(use_this)
mn_l = min(use_this)

fctr = (mx - mn)/(mx_l - mn_l)

use_this = [round((fctr * (x - mn_l)) + mn, 0) for x in use_this]

print(use_this)
```

**Note**:

1. `sin()` is monotonically increasing between `0 and pi/2` and decreasing between `pi/2 and pi`
2. Used the logic at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295202/14739759)

Comment: Nice trick. But, although it does give an ascending/descending order, the uniformity of the random distribution is broken by the sin function.  Also, it doesn't give results in the min_value...max_value range (although that would be easy to fix)

Comment: was uniformity a requirement? the other I agree (min-max)

Comment: well the use of `random.uniform` in this case was to generate values between `0 and pi`

Comment: @AlainT., fixed the min-max problem