# Finding the value of a point on a scaled line

Tags: javascript, math

Given 2 line segments with known starting and ending points, what formula would be used for a given point on line 1 as projected onto line 2?

Line 1

```
0.01  x       0.15
 |----|--------|
```

Line 2

```
 2      51         175
 |------|----------|
```

How do you find the value of x?

Comment: also: [How to scale down a range of numbers with a known min and max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294955/how-to-scale-down-a-range-of-numbers-with-a-known-min-and-max-value) for more general discussion.

Comment: `(175 - 2)/(0.15 - 0.01) = (51 - 2)/(X - 0.01)`